# Split by bs4 tag/Get text between two tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, beautifulsoup

Currently I trying to read the text between two tags from a webpage.

This is my code so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

text = soup.text

tag_one = soup.select_one('div.first-header')


tage_two = soup.select_one('div.second-header')



text = text.split(tag_one)[1]
text = text.split(tage_two)[0]

print(text)
```

Basically I am trying to get the text between the first and second header by identifying their tags. I was planning on to do this by splitting by the first tag and second tag.
Is this even possible? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Example:
If you look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

I would like to find a way to extract the text under "History" by identifying the tags of "History" and "Features and philosophy" and splitting by these tags.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include test input and expected output? It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cody I tried now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup 4.7+, the CSS select ability is much improved. This task can be done utilizing the CSS4 `:has()` selector that is now supported in BeautifulSoup:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, "lxml")
els = soup.select('h2:has(span#History) ~ *:has(~ h2:has(span#Features_and_philosophy))')
with codecs.open('text.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    for el in els:
        print(el.get_text())
```

The output:

```
 Guido van Rossum at OSCON 2006.Main article: History of PythonPython was conceived in the late 1980s[31] by Guido van Rossum at Centrum Wiskunde & Informatica (CWI) in the Netherlands as a successor to the ABC language (itself inspired by SETL)[32], capable of exception handling and interfacing with the Amoeba operating system.[7] Its implementation began in December 1989.[33] Van Rossum's long influence on Python is reflected in the title given to him by the Python community: Benevolent Dictator For Life (BDFL) –  a post from which he gave himself permanent vacation on July 12, 2018.[34]
Python 2.0 was released on 16 October 2000 with many major new features, including a cycle-detecting garbage collector and support for Unicode.[35]
Python 3.0 was released on 3 December 2008. It was a major revision of the language that is not completely backward-compatible.[36] Many of its major features were backported to Python 2.6.x[37] and 2.7.x version series.  Releases of Python 3 include the 2to3 utility, which automates (at least partially) the translation of Python 2 code to Python 3.[38]
Python 2.7's end-of-life date was initially set at 2015 then postponed to 2020 out of concern that a large body of existing code could not easily be forward-ported to Python 3.[39][40] In January 2017, Google announced work on a Python 2.7 to Go transcompiler to improve performance under concurrent workloads.[41]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it the way you're hoping because BS4 works on the dom, a tree-structure, rather than something linear.

Using your wiki example, what you're really looking for is

1. find id="History" (it's a span)
2. Navigate up to the H2 element -- remember that as the starting point.
3. find id="Features_and_philosophy" (it's another span)
4. Navigate up to the nearest H2 element -- remember that as the ending point.

Now, notice that the two H2 elements are siblings (they have the same parent). So what you're looking to do is get each sibling between starting H2 and ending H2, and, for each sibling, get the full text of each sibling.

That's not hard, but it's a loop, where you're comparing each sibling until you reach your ending one. Nothing as simple as you'd hoped.

In a more general case, it's much harder (or tedious, really), in that you may have to go up and down the DOM tree looking for the matching element.